# Is the N600, C3700 cable of running an alternative firmware?

Tags: firmware, flashing

I've been exploring WW-DRT and openwrt.org. I can find information on how to Flash WNDR3700 but nothing much appears to come up on this particular module N600, C3700.

**Question:**
To flash a open firmware, do  I follow instructions for [WNDR-3700](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNDR3700#DD-WRT_Installation) or N600? If so which version rev version.

[image: Router label]
[image: Router connection]

Errata: This is a spare model, not my primary (or even secondary) router. If I brick it, I'll call it a lessened learned and go on to the next project.

Comment: If there is not firmware specific for your model, you should not use DD-WRT, it will not work.  Those two models are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't achieve anything - there are ***no official modem router models*** currently supported by DD-WRT. As such, you won't find any model similar enough to flash it and have a working system. Bricking the device is almost a guarantee.

I have spotted a forum thread for your model with this also confirmed [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=942687).